# Heroku + Docker + Django Rest Framework

Tags: docker, heroku, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I have tried to Deploy my django REST application to heroku using docker. But I have received following error in Chrome console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) /favicon.ico.
Please, help me. I've tried tried to find it on the internet, but I haven't found exact situation.

**Heroku Logs:**

```
2018-03-31T00:11:34.645598+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-journey-46603.herokuapp.com request_id=f302df33-d8f5-493e-acc3-9876e62e6b1e fwd="92.243.107.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-03-31T00:11:35.739405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-journey-46603.herokuapp.com request_id=e92508cd-fcda-4aa2-b163-b048127782dc fwd="92.243.107.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-03-31T00:11:40.956628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-journey-46603.herokuapp.com request_id=e764b5be-2ecd-4d89-9c37-940330a89fec fwd="92.243.107.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-03-31T00:11:42.282073+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-journey-46603.herokuapp.com request_id=4f2b76d6-ed90-4deb-b4fd-6c5a4d95d7ff fwd="92.243.107.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-03-31T00:58:46.065190+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-journey-46603.herokuapp.com request_id=d0f5533d-eb96-4133-a996-f307c99cb387 fwd="92.243.107.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-03-31T00:58:47.659835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-journey-46603.herokuapp.com request_id=bd6eeee7-4e0c-45c5-b7a6-48e8aa0502e6 fwd="92.243.107.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-03-31T01:21:05.606596+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2018-03-31T01:21:30.451682+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3`

2018-03-31T01:21:34.767047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0

2018-03-31T01:21:34.886271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ADD . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: "postgres"
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "fbva"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "111111"

  django_app:
    container_name: "django_app"
    build: .
    env_file:
      - "fbva/fbva/.env"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    entrypoint:
      - ./entrypoint.sh
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py collectstatic
python3 manage.py loaddata ./fixtures/language.json
python3 manage.py loaddata ./fixtures/interval.json
python3 manage.py loaddata ./fixtures/setting.json
python3 manage.py loaddata ./fixtures/user.json
python3 manage.py loaddata ./fixtures/card.json
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

exec "$@"
```

**Deployed to Heroku using following commands:**

```
heroku login
heroku container:login
heroku container:push web
heroku open
```

---

[image: I've got this result]

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please add related logs/expected input/expected output.